# Powershell Export to csv - dynamic daterange

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv with user and datetime

```
Users DHMS          
----- ----          
A     22/12/21 05:02:00
B     22/12/21 05:10:00
C     22/12/21 06:30:00
D     23/12/21 12:30:00
A     23/12/21 12:35:00
B     23/12/21 12:45:00
C     26/12/21 10:32:00
D     28/12/21 11:15:00
A     29/12/21 14:17:00
B     29/12/21 14:25:00
```

Is there a simple way to extract from each row a new csv with the rows beetween -30 minutes   / + 30 minutes

I try to do this

```
$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
$Data = Import-Csv '.\test.csv' 

$Data | ForEach-Object {

    $DHMS = [DateTime]::ParseExact($($_.DHMS), 'dd/MM/yy HH:m:s', $culture)

    
$DHMSmoins = $DHMS.AddMinutes(-30)
$DHMSplus =  $DHMS.AddMinutes(30)


$path = ".\" + $($_.Users) +"\time.csv"


$Data | where { $DHMS  -ge $DHMSmoins  -and $DHMS -le $DHMSplus }
$Data | Export-Csv $path

}
```

but problems :

1/ daterange export is bad

2/ there is several users so only the last user's row is exported. Is there a way to concatenate the differents csv in one

Hope to be more clear for Tomalak

In A folder
a csv with

```
A     22/12/21 05:02:00
B     22/12/21 05:10:00
D     23/12/21 12:30:00
A     23/12/21 12:35:00
B     23/12/21 12:45:00
A     29/12/21 14:17:00
B     29/12/21 14:25:00
```

in B folder
a csv with

```
A     22/12/21 05:02:00
B     22/12/21 05:10:00
D     23/12/21 12:30:00
A     23/12/21 12:35:00
B     23/12/21 12:45:00
A     29/12/21 14:17:00
B     29/12/21 14:25:00
```

In C folder
a csv with

```
C     22/12/21 06:30:00
C     26/12/21 10:32:00
```

In D folder
a csv with

```
D     23/12/21 12:30:00
A     23/12/21 12:35:00
B     23/12/21 12:45:00
D     28/12/21 11:15:00
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your output is supposed to look like. Making groups of rows by date is possible, but then each group will contain multiple different `Users` values. How does that translate to an output path like `".\$($_.Users)\time.csv"`?

Comment: I create one directory for each user and want to place one csv with the range datetime -30 / +30 minutes for each row with this user

Comment: So you want an additional level of grouping per user? Your question does not really tell that.

Comment: No grouping per user in csv. I group in a directory user that i have created. I Hope i'm clear sorry

Comment: The desired output is still unclear. Please work from your sample data and show all the CSV files you want to create from that, their names, and which rows they are supposed to contain.

Comment: Sorry, i edited the question with the samples data expected

Comment: Okay, so in plain English - correct me if I'm wrong: You want one folder per user ("grouped by user") with a CSV file that contains all the events of that user, plus half an hour of "context" before and after each (independently of which user they belong to).

Comment: Exactly. Sorry for my english :)

Comment: You are showing the CSV input as a table.  That's easy to read,  but the actual CSV text might be more informative for our purposes.  It's not clear whether you expect fields to be separated by commas or semicolons.  That's culture dependent,  and at least one of the answers is from a European culture where the answer is semicolon.

Comment: The Export-Csv is definitely in the wrong place.  You don't invoke this cmdlet once for each record.  Instead you pipe the record stream to Export-CSV which you invoke once.   Internally,  Powershell turns your single invocation into an invocation that is inside a loop,  but that's how pipelines work.  You don't have to do that work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Task as per the comments:

> one folder per user ("grouped by user") with a CSV file that contains all the events of that user, plus half an hour of "context" before and after each (independently of which user they belong to).

Here's how I would do it:

```
$rows = Import-Csv '.\test.csv' -Delimiter ";" | foreach {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        date = [DateTime]::ParseExact($_.DHMS, 'dd/MM/yy HH:m:s', [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
        row = $_
    }
}

$rows | group { $_.row.Users } | foreach {
    $user = $_.Name
    $filename = ".\$user\time.csv"

    # get context events (n.b.: this will contain duplicates!)
    $events = $_.Group | foreach {
        $start = $_.date.AddMinutes(-30)
        $until = $_.date.AddMinutes(30)
        ($rows | where { $_.date -ge $start -and $_.date -le $until }).row
    }

    # consolidate duplicates
    $index = @{}
    $uniqueEvents = foreach ($event in $events) {
        if (-not $index.ContainsKey($event)) {
            $index[$event] = $true
            $event
        }
    }

    Write-Host $filename -ForegroundColor Cyan
    Write-Host ($uniqueEvents | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation) -Separator "`r`n"  -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
    # $uniqueEvents | Export-Csv $filename -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
}
```

which prints the desired output for your sample data:

```
.\A\time.csv
"Users";"DHMS"
"A";"22/12/21 05:02:00"
"B";"22/12/21 05:10:00"
"D";"23/12/21 12:30:00"
"A";"23/12/21 12:35:00"
"B";"23/12/21 12:45:00"
"A";"29/12/21 14:17:00"
"B";"29/12/21 14:25:00"
.\B\time.csv
"Users";"DHMS"
"A";"22/12/21 05:02:00"
"B";"22/12/21 05:10:00"
"D";"23/12/21 12:30:00"
"A";"23/12/21 12:35:00"
"B";"23/12/21 12:45:00"
"A";"29/12/21 14:17:00"
"B";"29/12/21 14:25:00"
.\C\time.csv
"Users";"DHMS"
"C";"22/12/21 06:30:00"
"C";"26/12/21 10:32:00"
.\D\time.csv
"Users";"DHMS"
"D";"23/12/21 12:30:00"
"A";"23/12/21 12:35:00"
"B";"23/12/21 12:45:00"
"D";"28/12/21 11:15:00"
```